# Display Firebase storage images in a RecyclerView Android Studio without Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am a beginner with `Java` and am trying to make my first app. In my application, I was able to upload images to `Firebase Storage`, and now I wanted to display all these images in a `RecyclerView`. All the images in the `"images /"` folder show in a recycle view, but I want to use only the `Firebase storage`, not the database. I just need to show the pictures. I readed the `Firebase` documentation but could not do it.

Is it possible?

sorry for English.

Comment: please refer firebase storage tutorials ;)

Comment: There is currently no API to get a list of files from Cloud Storage through the Firebase SDK. If you want to show all lists in a folder or bucket, you will have to get that list of files from somewhere. If you don't want to store it in a database, you could store it in a file with a known name, like `files_list`, and update that every time.

Comment: ohh, I will need to use Database anyway. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know the proper name of that image which url you want to get from firebase storage then you can get the image without saving that image url in any database and if you dont know the image name then you can not get that particular image url.